# Twitter like row hover reply,delete links in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter, hover, row

Is there any plugin or how to display twitter like row hover reply,delete links in jquery....
Any suggestion....

**EDIT:**

I am iterating my json data via jquery,

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
                    divs += '<div class="resultsdiv">
                 <a href=Clients/Show/' + this.ClientId + '/>Details</div>';
                });
```

What it does my details link is shown in all rows... I want to show like twitter on row hover i wnat to show details link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initially hide your details links, and only shows it on mouse hover by hooking an event handler to [hover event](http://api.jquery.com/hover).

So based on your code snippet, you would probably do something like this:

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
    $(divs).append('<div class="resultsdiv" style="display:none">
            <a href=Clients/Show/' + this.ClientId + '/>Details</div>').hover(function() {
        var $anchor = $(this).find('a');
        if $anchor.is(':hidden') {
            $anchor.show();
        } else {
            $anchor.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use [the other variant of hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1) where you provide two callback functions, one for mouse moving in and the other for mouse moving out. That way you can explicitly show/hide the anchor based on the corresponding event.

Comment: i dont want to hide the div because it contains data i only want to hide anchor tags within it and show them only on hover...

Comment: i only want to hide the anchor tags... How to do that?

Comment: My bad. I changed the example to check and show/hide only the anchor element.